# one to one set up does allows multiple records in parent table to be related to one record other related table

Tags: jpa

Please be so kind to help me understand why, by running attached code, I have multiple records been written in parent table from my data base (MySQL) with corresponding to a record in related table, although the set up in Java code is for one to one relation (i.e. one records in parent corresponding to only one record in other related table.

I am at your disposal for any questions you might have on the subject.

many thank for support
petrisor

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        createParkingLot();
        AddEmployees(1);
        AddEmployees(2);
}
public static void createParkingLot(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("java2curs4e1PU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ParkingLot p1= new ParkingLot();
        p1.setParking_lot_no(1);
        try{
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(p1);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
}

public static void AddEmployees(int employee_number){
        EntityManagerFactory emf =  
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("java2curs4e1PU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ParkingLot p2 = em.find(ParkingLot.class,1);
        Employee a1 = new Employee();
        a1.setEmployee_name("Employee_name_#"+employee_number);
        a1.setParking_lot(p2);
        try{
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(a1);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
}

}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
related entities description:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Entity Employee
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employees")
 public class Employee implements Serializable{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
 private int id;
 private String employee_name;
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional = false,fetch = 
 FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_parking_lot")
 private ParkingLot parking_lot;

 public int getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public String getEmployee_name() {
    return employee_name;
 }

public void setEmployee_name(String employee_name) {
    this.employee_name = employee_name;
}

public ParkingLot getParking_lot() {
    return parking_lot;
}

public void setParking_lot(ParkingLot parking_lot) {
    this.parking_lot = parking_lot;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + employee_name + ", 
 parking lot=" + parking_lot + '}';
}

}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Entity ParkingLot:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "parking_lots")
 public class ParkingLot implements Serializable{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
 private int id;
 private int parking_lot_no;
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = 
 false,mappedBy = "parking_lot")
 private Employee employee;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getParking_lot_no() {
    return parking_lot_no;
}
public void setParking_lot_no(int parking_lot_no) {
    this.parking_lot_no = parking_lot_no;
}
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "ParkingLot{" + "id=" + id + ", parking lot number=" + 
parking_lot_no + '}';
}
}
```

Normally I would expect the program to through an exception as I tried to insert another Employee (Employee_name_#2) with the same parking lot (id 1).

Instead in table employees I found that I have 2 employees with same parking lot.

Comment: Have you added a unique constraint on the id_parking_lot column of the employees table? If not, then then database doesn't know that there can only be one employee with a given parking lot, and you thus get no exception.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, my understanding was that JPA allows data base setup through java code (using proper annotation) without intervening sepatatelly in the setup of the database.

Comment: Hibernate should create a unique constraint for you, and you can also use the JPA annotations to explicitly create one. But in the long run, you'll need a more powwerful tool anyway to migrate your schema from one version to another( like FlywayDB), so why not start now?